# Case operator returning string instead of integer (my-sql)

Tags: mysql

While solving this [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/rank-scores/description/) in leet-code, I write the following query but the **CASE** operator returning string instead of integer. How to solve this problem?

```
select Score, (case 
                   when @prev_score = Score then @rank
                   when (@prev_score := Score) then @rank := @rank + 1
              end) as Rank
from Scores, (select @rank := 0, @prev_score := null) as a order by Score desc
```

Instead of returning `[[4.0,1],[4.0,1],[3.85,2],[3.65,3],[3.65,3],[3.5,4]]` its return `[[4.0,"1"],[4.0,"1"],[3.85,"2"],[3.65,"3"],[3.65,"3"],[3.5,"4"]]`

Comment: How are you determining it's a string that is returned? Surely the double quotes aren't present. It looks like a number when I do it [here on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0cd91a/22).

Comment: You can submit the query into the problem link to view the result. So you say its leet-code judge system problem.

Comment: In [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59454/1) table Name is a varchar field and in resultant query it doesn't returning any double quote, that doesn't mean Name is integer field.

Comment: But mysql NEVER returns a double quote around non-numerics unless you concatenate them in there or they are present in the data. That is purely some oddball behavior of leet-code. Which is why I asked how you were determining it was non-numeric return. Definitely 100% chalk this up to Leet-Code's poor implementation. You can try wrapping that CASE with an explicit cast to integer, but... if your answer is returning the correct results, then you are good (at least as far as I'm concerned).

Comment: I guess the better way to say that first sentence is that, while a result set returned though ODBC, OLEDB, JDBC, etc has a `type` for each field, it's up to the client on how it wants to display it. In the case of this query I can't imagine that the result set would show a non-numeric type given that the result is determined via arithmetic. Not only is the leet-code "client" odd for showing double quotes, it's wrong too.